# Using findInterval after discretization in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining

After discretizing a variable (interval method), I'm having trouble checking if a value belongs to an interval.

Discretizing `c(1:10)` in a vector `a`:

`(a<-unique(discretize(1:10,method="interval",5)))`

`[1] [ 1.0, 2.8) [ 2.8, 4.6) [ 4.6, 6.4) [ 6.4, 8.2) [ 8.2,10.0]`

and then checking in which interval the value *4* is in yelds:

`for(i in 1:5){print(findInterval(x=4,a[i]))}`

`[1] 1`

`[1] 1`

`[1] 1`

`[1] 1`

`[1] 0`

while it should result in `0 1 0 0 0`

What am I doing wrong? the discretize function and findInterval don't work well together?

EDIT:
Another related question:
why after discretizing a column I get repeated values when I souldnt?, i.e.,

`(a<-discretize(1:10,method="interval",5))
 [1] [ 1.0, 2.8) [ 1.0, 2.8) [ 2.8, 4.6) [ 2.8, 4.6) [ 4.6, 6.4) [ 4.6, 6.4) [ 6.4, 8.2)
 [8] [ 6.4, 8.2) [ 8.2,10.0] [ 8.2,10.0]`

Comment: Where does this `discretize` function come from? It doesn't seem to be in base R.

Comment: It is from the arules package

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using findInterval incorrectly. Your vector, a, doesn't need to be in that form. You only need a vector of the threshold points defining the intervals. try this

```
a<-seq(1,10, length.out=6)
findInterval(4,a)
```